# Django-haystack returns results with "simple" backend, but not with "whoosh"

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm trying to integrate a search with django-haystack,
While it works well with the "sample" backend, when replacing the backend with whoosh it always returns 0 results.

settings.py:

```
HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR = 'AND'
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'search_sites'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_ENGINE = 'whoosh'
HAYSTACK_SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 20
HAYSTACK_WHOOSH_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'search_index')
```

search_sites.py

```
import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()
```

profiles/search_indexes.py:

```
from haystack import indexes
from haystack import site

from profiles.models import Profile


class ProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Profile.objects.all()

site.register(Profile, ProfileIndex)
```

templates/search/indexes/profiles/profile_text.txt:

```
{{ profile.name }}
{{ profile.description }}
```

Running `python manage.py rebuild_index` returns:

```
All documents removed.
Indexing 60 profiles.
```

When running the following in the shell:

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
>>> sqs.count()
0
```

When switching whoosh with the "simple" backend, everything works fine and 60 results are returned.

Everything seems to be set up correctly, according to [Getting Started with Haystack](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html), and [Debugging Haystack](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/debugging.html#no-results-found-on-the-web-page).
I tried installing previous version of Whoosh, without any success.

Feeling very stupid at this point, any help will be really appreciated.

Package Versions:

```
python==2.7  
Django==1.3.1  
Whoosh==2.3.2  
django-haystack==1.2.6
```

---

**Updates:**

- Downgrading Whoosh to 1.8.4 didn't help.
- When using the basic search template as described at the [Haystack Tutorial](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/tutorial.html#search-template), all results are returned for 1 letter queries, and 0 results for other searches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found it, and it was even more stupid then I though...

`templates/search/indexes/profiles/profile_text.txt` should be:

```
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.description }}
```

And not:

```
{{ profile.name }}
{{ profile.description }}
```

What confused me was that the "simple" backend that matches against the database, and apparently ignores the data template.